# Mocking Cookies with Angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies, jasmine

In my main `describe` I have the following:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(...) {
    var mockCookieService = {
        _cookies: {},
        get: function(key) {
            return this._cookies[key];
        },
        put: function(key, value) {
            this._cookies[key] = value;
        }
    }

   cookieService = mockCookieService;

   mainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
       ...
       $cookieStore: cookieService
   }
}
```

Later on I want to test how a controller believes if the cookie already exists, so I nest the following describe:

```
describe('If the cookie already exists', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        cookieService.put('myUUID', 'TEST');
    });

    it('Should do not retrieve UUID from server', function() {
        expect(userService.getNewUUID).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

However when I'm making the change to `cookieService` it's not persisting into the controller being created.  Am I taking the wrong approach?

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Updated the testing code and this is how I'm using $cookieStore:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', ['UserService', 'ngCookies']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, UserService, $cookieStore) {
var uuid = $cookieStore.get('myUUID');

if (typeof uuid == 'undefined') {
    UserService.getNewUUID().$then(function(response) {
        uuid = response.data.uuid;
        $cookieStore.put('myUUID', uuid);
    });
}
```

});

Comment: Can you show how $cookieStore is used in your controller? And how do you test the controller?

Comment: Updated, let me know if you need more of the test code.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not persisting into the controller"? Do you want to say your controller is not using the mockup? Or do you mean when you call `$cookieStore.get()`, you can't get expected value back?

Comment: If I call `cookieService.put(...)` in the `beforeEach` of that nested describe block, then when I log `$cookieStore.get(...)` inside the controller it comes back as undefined as if it doesn't see the cookie I am trying to mock in.

Comment: I see. Make sure controller is actually calling the method of the mock. Try to create a plunk or fiddle if you can, that will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your unit tests need not have to create a mock $cookieStore and essentially re-implement its functionality. You can use Jasmine's `spyOn` function to create a spy object and return values.

Create a stub object

```
var cookieStoreStub = {};
```

Set up your spy object before creating the controller

```
spyOn(cookieStoreStub, 'get').and.returnValue('TEST'); //Valid syntax in Jasmine 2.0+. 1.3 uses andReturnValue()

mainCtrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
 ... 
 $cookieStore: cookieStoreStub 
}
```

Write unit tests for the scenario in which cookie is available

```
describe('If the cookie already exists', function() {
    it('Should not retrieve UUID from server', function() {
        console.log(cookieStore.get('myUUID')); //Returns TEST, regardless of 'key'
        expect(userService.getNewUUID).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Note: If you'd like to test multiple `cookieStore.get()` scenarios, you might want to move the creation of the controller into a `beforeEach()` inside the `describe()` block. This allows you to call `spyOn()` and return a value appropriate for the describe block.